# React Hooks/Typescript: "TypeError: blogs.map is not a function" (and I've type'd blogs as an 'Array')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, fetch

I built a blog web app a few months back. It worked correctly back then but, upon revisiting it now, the blogs will not load with a GET fetch request. I'm given an "internal server error" in Postman and "Uncaught TypeError: blogs.map is not a function" in my console.

I've updated npm and its dependencies, and resolved all errors marked in red in my code editor.

I've dug around SO and the internet, and it seems like the only solution I can find is "you're type'ing the fetched data as a 'string' when you need to type it as an 'Array' - but I've type'd mine correctly.

**My code:**

Home.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { IBlog } from "../utils/interfaces";
import BlogPreview from "../components/BlogPreview";
import { json } from "../utils/api";

export interface HomeProps {}

const Home: React.SFC<HomeProps> = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState<IBlog[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        let blogs = await json("/api/blogs");
        setBlogs(blogs);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })();
  }, []); 

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h2 className="row m-4 justify-content-center text-secondary">
          Blog Feed
        </h2>
      </div>
      <main className="col">
        <section className="row my-5 justify-content-center">
          {blogs.map(blog => {
            return <BlogPreview key={`blog-${blog.id}`} blog={blog} />;
          })}
        </section>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

interfaces.ts

```
export interface IBlog {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    content: string,
    _created: Date,
    name: string
}
```

routes.ts

```
import { Router, Request } from "express";
import db from "../../db";

router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let blogs = await db.Blogs.getAll();
    res.json(blogs);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});

export default router;
```

api.ts

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

export let AccessToken: string = localStorage.getItem('token') || null;
export let User: any = {
    userid: localStorage.getItem('userid') || null,
    role: localStorage.getItem('role') || null
}

export const json = async <T = any>(uri: string, method: string = 'GET', body?: {}) => {
    let headers: any = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    };

    if (AccessToken) {
        headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${AccessToken}`;
    }
    try {
        let result = await fetch(uri, {
            method,
            headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        });
        if (result.ok) {
            return <T>(await result.json());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    }
};

export const SetAccessToken = (token: string, user: {} = { userid: undefined, role: 'guest'}) => {
    AccessToken = token;
    User = user;
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('userid', User.userid);
    localStorage.setItem('role', User.role);
}
```

I've tried fiddling with some code on both frontend and backend because it seems like the error is affecting both? Still kind of clueless though. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm guessing that `await json("/api/blogs");` is returning `null`. Can you post the `json` method?

Comment: @AlexWayne, Sorry I'm unfamiliar with what that is (I built this blog during bootcamp, so I don't understand every bit of the code). However, I've added to my post what I believe you asked for; it's the "api.ts" section.

Comment: Under `let blogs = await json("/api/blogs");` add a `console.log(blogs)`. What do you get? Also check the network tab of your browser debugger. Are requests being made successfully?

Comment: with `console.log(blogs)` I just get the same errors. In my Terminal, I see a 500 status for the request. In Network tab, all requests are successful except the GET request. I should note that the entire page loads initially, but then everything goes blank (except for the background image) once the GET request fires.

Comment: In addition to ^ I get the "ECONNREFUSED" error, but I'm not sure if that matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based your additional information here's what happening.

Your request from your react app is failing. The server is responding with a:

> HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

If we look at your route, we can see where that `500` error comes from:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let blogs = await db.Blogs.getAll();
    res.json(blogs);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

This means that `db.Blogs.getAll();` is throwing an error, logging it to the console, and then returning the HTTP 500 status.

Then in the code that makes the request, there is this logic:

```
    if (result.ok) {
        return <T>(await result.json());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

The result of the request was *not* ok, it was a server error. So `false` is returned. This means that `await json("/api/blogs");` returns false. Which means when you do:

```
setBlogs(blogs);
```

You are really doing this, which isn't what you want.

```
setBlogs(false);
```

I can't tell you how to fix this, but this info should help you debug it. I would start by looking in your command line terminal for any errors being logged out there. Perhaps your server cannot connect the database for some reason? Or perhaps something else entirely.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Alex! Your explanation helped me understand the error better, and I was actually just starting to look into my DB to see if that's the issue, so I agree that that is likely where the problem lies.